# Somebody Has used the lepton-NodeJs for compression JPGs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dropbox, dropbox-sdk-js

I want compress some JPGs for update to the DB, this code is the only thing I found with documentation but I do not see what it is that needs to be uploaded to the database I know it's the file.lep but I do not know where to take it. https://github.com/whitef0x0/node-lepton

[image]

Comment: JPEGs are already compressed.

Comment: Please do not include images of text. Instead, copy the relevant text to the question. This increases searchability, protects against the image going away at some point, *and* allows others to help with your question since they can copy and paste if/when needed.

Comment: @SLaks I need to compress more

Comment: @mscdex  sorry I put the url now

Answer (score 0):

Read the documentation:

> These functions takes a callback that returns an error object and the output in form of a binary file blob.

The `data` parameter is exactly what you're looking for.